# Enabling auto-updates in RubyMine

Tags: ruby, auto-update, rubymine, rubymine-7

Is there a way to enable autoupdating in RubyMine? According to [this page](https://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/help/updates.html), you can

> Use this page *[i.e. "File | Settings | Appearance and Behavior | System Settings | Updates"]* to:
>
> - Enable automatic update of RubyMine and specify to which kind of release you want it updated.

However, when I actually look at that menu, all I see is this:

[image: A checkbox labelled "Automatically check updates for" with a text box beside it with "New Major Versions" inside; below is another checkbox and some information about my RubyMine install.]

Further searching yields no results. Since the page is labelled as "RubyMine 7.1.0 Help", I'd assume that it's up-to-date for 7.1.2, so how can I enable autoupdates? Did they simply forget to update this little chunk of the help documentation?

All of my Google searches turned up absolutely nothing - all the results are about autocompletion or updates in general (i.e. the page I linked at the top) or updating manually or something entirely unrelated in a different IDE or... this question. Huh. Hi, Google!

Note: Yes, it *is* possible to manually update it from this menu, by clicking <kbd>Check Now</kbd>. I'm explicitly *not* looking for that. I want RubyMine to search for updates and install them on its own, preferably when it starts.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR version: RubyMine can and will check for updates very regularly, if you select the type of update you'd like. 
As far as I know, it will not **install** it, without asking, but it will automatically **check** for an update upon starting the app.

Longer version:

First of all 7.1.2 is the most current version of RubyMine, so I wouldn't expect RubyMine to update.

As far as I understand the RubyMine versioning "New Major Releases" means a change in the first number of a version. With that setting you'd get an update information for version 8. If you prefer to get updates more frequently, try one of the other option the Update-Settings provide (see screenshot)

[image]

On my machine 7.1.2 installed upon starting RubyMine (but after asking whether I wanted the update to happen). So, it didn't autoinstall without asking for permission.

Comment: My issue is that it doesn't even ask for it to install when it starts. You have a point with the 'New Major Releases" part, though -- when I get a chance I'm gonna test that.

Comment: ...Apologies for forgetting, but I did go back and test it; your solution worked. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, "New Major Version Releases" ("includes all RubyMine releases, for example, RubyMine X.Y.Z")[https://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/help/updates.html]. IMHO JetBrains fails in both documentation and UI about this section, and it's a bug. Label should be something like "New Stable Releases" and documentation should say "Enable automatic update **check**[..]".

Answer (score 1):

Currently, Rubymine is in version 2016.1.1b and full transparent auto-update isn't still implemented as far I could see in my Linux (Ubuntu-based distro).

Here, the auto-update is more a auto-detect updates feature, who will ask me to accept the update and let it installs and restart automatically.

Which isn't currently a straightforward method also, because I installed it on `/opt` and to have right permission to update and it notifies me, I have to call manually `rubymine.sh` as root and then accept the update - `sudo mine` won't work.